# Optimization Methods in Banach Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-analysis

does anyone know if there's a theory for the following problem:
Optimize the task

$\begin{align*}
T_\phi(\tilde{u})&=\inf\limits_u T_\phi(u)\\
Au&=b\\
u&\in L^p(\Omega),\,\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align*}$

for (nonlinear map) $A:L^p(\Omega)\to Z$, with $Z$ arbitrary local convex topological vector space and $T_\phi:L^p(\Omega)\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ defined by

$\int\limits_{\Omega}\phi(u(x))\,dx$

a weakly lower semiconinous convex function, with weakly compact level set. The map $\phi$ is also lower semiconinous convex.

Or exist there a theorem, that such a problem possess a optimal solution?

Comment: My idee was to use the theory of monoton operators, but the problem is that the image of $A$ is not $(L^p)^*$.

Comment: Are there any more conditions on $A$? Without any additional conditions, you don't necessarily have minimizers.

Comment: The question is what conditions must be placed on a nonlinear A for the task to have a non-trivial solution.

Comment: If I replaced $Z$ with $(L^p)^*$ and suppose $A$ is monotonous, hemistic and coercive, then there should be a solution to the problem. This would follow from the theorem of Browder and Minty.